# ASP.net MVC Web Deployment Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment, web-deployment-project

I created an ASP.net MVC 2 Web Application in Visual Studio 2010. I then added a Web Deployment Project to the solution and added the Primary Output from my web application. I right clicked on the web deployment project in Visual Studio and clicked Install and ran through the install. I then tried to use IIS to browse to the page and got the following:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I browse to the folder that the application is and all I see is a bin folder and inside that there are just a few dll's. No web.config. Nothing else. Is there something else I need to add to the deployment project other than primary output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the Content Files from the Project as well. Once I added both Content Files and Primary Output everything worked fine.